# quadcopter specification

Tags: quadcopters, multirotor, battery-cell, battery-discharge-rating

https://www.droneassemble.com/product/quadcopter-drone-90-minutes-endurance/ This quadcopter offers a 90-minute flight time on a 14S-14000mah Li-ion battery. The propellers being used have a 22-inch x 8-inch blade and an 8 kg MTOW. Is this specification sensible? If so, could you please explain how?

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess it can only do 90 minutes at it's minimum weight (5.4kg) and loading it up to 8kg would halve the flight time.

Compared to a DJI Mavic, it's got about 20 times the rotor area, and 10 times the battery energy. It weighs 5-10 times as much, so it's reasonable that it could double the Mavic's 45 minute duration.

Of course, a much cheaper way to fly for 90 minutes would be to buy a second battery for a cheaper drone.